# String Concat not working in scope JS

Tags: javascript, concatenation, string-concatenation

### Unable to make String Concat work

In the code below I am not able to concat the variable `temp` to the variable `newString`. I have tested and seen that this is not an issue of scoping but I am still puzzled by this behavior.

**Understanding the objective of the code**

Below you can see an example of the code which takes an object with K (a number) and S (a string). The function is meant to shift the character's position in the alphabet by the number K while keeping itself as Upper or Lowercase for a given String S.

```
function shiftCharByInt(args){
  const numb = args.K
  const word = args.S
  let newString = ''

  for(let i=0;i<word.length;i++){
      let character = word.charAt(i)
      if(/^[a-z]+$/.test(character)){
          let indexOfChar = character.charCodeAt(0)
          indexOfChar+=numb
          while(indexOfChar > 122) indexOfChar -= 26;
          let temp = String.fromCharCode(indexOfChar)
          newString.concat(temp)
          continue;
      }
      if(/^[A-Z]+$/.test(character)){
          let indexOfChar = character.charCodeAt(0)
          indexOfChar+=numb
          while(indexOfChar > 90) indexOfChar -= 26;
          let temp = String.fromCharCode(indexOfChar)
          newString.concat(temp)
          continue;
      }
      newString += word
  }
  return newString
}
```

Example Input:

```
{
  K: 11,
  S: 'Hello - World'
}
```

Example Output:

```
"Spwwz - Hzcwo"
```

Again, I am more interested in understanding why concat does not work optimising the code itself.

Comment: Could you provide example output as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not saving the value back to `newString` (`concat` **doesn't mutate the string value**), replace it by

```
newString = newString.concat(temp);
```

and

```
newString = newString + word;//outside if
```

Also **you can't re-assign a value to `const`**, so replace

```
const newString = ''
```

with

```
var newString = ''
```

**Demo**

```js
function test(args){
  const numb = args.K
  const word = args.S
  var newString = ''

  for(let i=0;i<word.length;i++){
    debugger
      let character = word.charAt(i)
      if(/^[a-z]+$/.test(character)){
          let indexOfChar = character.charCodeAt(0)
          indexOfChar+=numb
          while(indexOfChar > 122) indexOfChar -= 26;
          let temp = String.fromCharCode(indexOfChar)
          newString = newString.concat(temp)
          continue;
      }
      if(/^[A-Z]+$/.test(character)){
          let indexOfChar = character.charCodeAt(0)
          indexOfChar+=numb
          while(indexOfChar > 90) indexOfChar -= 26;
          let temp = String.fromCharCode(indexOfChar)
          newString = newString.concat(temp)
          continue;
      }
      newString = newString + character; 
  }
  return newString
}

console.log(test({
  K: 11,
  S: 'Hello - World'
}));
```

Comment: thanks, yes the last bit was meant to be `newString = newString + character`

Comment: @William What is the expected output?

Comment: Another small error, I put `indexOfChar -= 25;` instead of `indexOfChar -= 26;` for the input recommended we expected: ""Spwwz - Hzcwo""

Comment: @William Check the edited code, you need to keep `newString = newString + character; `