# Why does JS concat method with foreach return empty string?

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

Newbie here so please excuse the ignorance. I wanted to know why my resulting variable is an empty string, when I loop through the array using forEach and concat method.

```
const concatSpeakersText = arr => {
    const speakerOneText = ''
    const speakerTwoText = ''

    arr.forEach(utterance => {
        utterance.speaker === '1' ? speakerOneText.concat(' ', utterance.text) : speakerTwoText.concat(' ', utterance.text)
    })

    console.log(speakerOneText)
    console.log(speakerTwoText)
}
```

Comment: you never use the result of concat.

Comment: Strings are immutable. `concat()` returns a new string, you need to assign it back to the variable.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+"concat"+doesn’t+change+string) of [String Concat not working in scope JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48744357/4642212). Read the [documentation of `concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat). This has nothing to do with `forEach`. You could’ve reduced your [mre] to `let str = ""; str.concat("string"); console.log(str);`.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the resources and feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign to a variable with [`String#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) or take an object with the speakers.

```
const concatSpeakersText = arr => {
    const speakers = { speakerOneText: '', speakerTwoText: '' };

    arr.forEach(utterance => {
        speakers[utterance.speaker === '1'
            ? 'speakerOneText'
            : 'speakerTwoText'
        ] += ' ' + utterance.text;
    });

    console.log(speakers.speakerOneText)
    console.log(speakers.speakerTwoText)
}
```